# Add custom headers to upload image

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm currently trying to integrate the [CKeditor 5 ReactComponent](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react) into my app.

I'm facing an issue with the upload image functionality... I use a Node/Express backend which uses a JWT auth middleware, so each request must have an `Authorization` header in order to pass.

I want to know if one of the following is possible:

- a way to add a custom header to the component
- a way to overwrite the upload handler and call a custom handler instead in which I can do what ever

Below is my code

```
<CKEditor
  editor={ClassicEditor}
  data="<p>Add product description here</p>"
  onInit={(editor) => {
    // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
    //console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
  }}
  onChange={(event, editor) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    this.handleData(data)
  }}
  config={{
    ckfinder: {
      uploadUrl: `${apiUrl}/upload/images/description`,
    },
  }}
/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it with this code in property onInit

```
onInit={ editor => {
 editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = function( loader ) {
  return new UploadAdapter( loader );
 };
}}
```

after you must create  the class UploadAdapter

```
class UploadAdapter {
  constructor( loader ) {
    // Save Loader instance to update upload progress.
    this.loader = loader;
  }

  upload() {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('typeOption', 'upload_image');
    data.append('file', this.loader.file);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios({
        url: `${API}forums`,
        method: 'post',
        data,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': tokenCopyPaste()
        },
        withCredentials: true
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        var resData = res.data;
        resData.default = resData.url;
        resolve(resData);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        reject(error)
      });
    });
  }

  abort() {
    // Reject promise returned from upload() method.
  }
}
```

Comment: The above code actually let's me use the image upload but the image is not uploaded. The `data` const is an empty `FormData` object so after the call is made there is no image uploaded.

Comment: remember that you have to return the url of the image that you have uploaded. you must return this data ('uploaded' => TRUE, 'url' => 'http://www.example/imgs/example.png')

Comment: there is no image uploaded to the server, so I cannot give a valid url back

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot this line of code -> data.append('file', this.loader.file);, I already edited the previous code

Comment: Below link there is very good explanation and sample code. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html